# Including a codeigniter snippit in another site

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to include a CI comment form in selected pages in an existing non CI site. I’ve tried using

```
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] = "cms/2";

//Set GET action,method params etc

require_once "path/to/index.php";
```

When I include the above code in a file outside the codeigniter root I get

> Your system folder path does not
>   appear to be set correctly. Please
>   open the following file and correct
>   this: index.php

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It was a relative path problem. The included file obviously uses the path of the calling function. I just needed to include

```
$application_folder = dirname(__FILE__)."/application";
$system_path = dirname(__FILE__)."/system";
```

in index.php