# Is it possible to access codeigniter functions/helpers from within Magento?

Tags: codeigniter, magento

I have a Codeigniter powered site at the root and a Magento powered product catalog inside a catalog folder. I was wondering if it is possible to load Codeigniter inside Magento so I can re-use partials, helpers, etc.

**For example:** I would like to share the same header in both platforms, so the header.php file in Codeigniter uses the url helper, and functions that Magento doesn't understand

How can I achieve this?

---

**UPDATE:**
I've tried the following:

```
CODEIGNITER
    |
    \_ CATALOG (Magento)
```

Inside Magento's index.php file I added:

```
include('../index.php');

$CI =& get_instance(); 
echo $CI->load->controller('welcome');
```

After this, I got an error "Can't find application folder" from Codeigniter when loading site/catalog. So something worked. I cheched this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182274/including-a-codeigniter-snippit-in-another-site/5182989#5182989) and inside Codeigniter index.php file I added:

```
$application_folder = dirname(__FILE__)."/application";
$system_path = dirname(__FILE__)."/system";
```

The first error was gone but then followed 5 php errors where it could not find CI/UTF8.php, CI/URI.php, CI/Benchmark.php... etc. These are CI core files which are referenced in the bootstap index.php.

This is where I'm stuck...

Comment: i've done used magento inside of ci so i assume it would work the other way :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to include your class files to your header templates and call the methods from external lib objects? Or better jet include already outputted header file?

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? Check out my update to see if that's what you mean.